# request.body.email is undefined node js server side using http.get

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, undefined, server-side

I have a problem where request.body.email returns me undefined.
I wrote this code on my controller on my client side:

```
 wish.controller('wishCtrl',['$scope','$http','$cookies',function($scope,$http,$cookies) {
    var user={};
    user.email = $cookies.get('cookieEmail');
    console.log(user.email);
     $http.get("http://localhost:3000/wishlist",user).success(function(data){

        $scope.wishController = data; 
        console.log(data);
    });

}]);
```

here I see - user.email ok so there is no problem here.

on my controller on my server side I wrote:

```
exports.getData = function(request, response) {
    userEmail = request.body.email;
    console.log(userEmail);
}
```

which writes me back undefined. 
to call this function I have on my server.js (on the server side)

```
app.get('/wishlist',wish.getData);
```

any idea how to fix it?

Comment: What is undefined? Your title says `request` is undefined but then you said `request.body.email` is undefined.

Comment: fixed it. thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

You are making a GET request. There is no request body in a GET request.

If you want to read query string data then [parse request.url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-express-js-on-node-js).

The [Angular documentation for get](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) says that the last argument must be a configuration object. So it looks like you aren't even managing to put your data in the URL either. Pass a configuration too.

```
$http.get("http://localhost:3000/wishlist",user, {})
```

Comment: so I can't get this object on my server side using $http.get?

Comment: @user3488862 — I didn't say that. You have to (a) Make sure the data is actually in the query string and (b) read the query string and not the (non-existent) body. As I said in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

because i't get function have to pass the email on the client side this way:

```
$http.get("http://localhost:3000/wishlist/"+user.email)
```

and the path of the sever should recognize it that way:

```
app.get('/wishlist/:email',wish.getData);
```

and int the controller that way:

```
userEmail = request.params.email;
console.log(userEmail);
```

Comment: request.body.email will also work if you send POST data. i.e $http.post("http://localhost//")