# $http.get('url', { params: { email: email } }); sending request with empty params

Tags: angularjs, http-get, angular-http, http-parameters

I am trying to send `HTTP GET` request with `email` in `params` in following code:

```
$http.get('api/me', {
    params: {
        email: email
    }
});
```

but at backend I am receiving empty params i.e. `request.params` is blank. I tried the other format of `HTTP` request i.e.

```
$http({
    url: 'api/me', 
    method: "GET",
    params: {email: email}
});
```

but result is same i.e. empty params at backend.

My backend code:

```
User.findOne({ email: request.params.email }, function(error, user) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    } else if (!user) {
        response.json({
            message: "User doesn't exist.",
            status: 0
        });
    } else {
        response.json({
            message: "Successfully logged in.",
            status: 1,
            data: user
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: First of all check if the email variable has a value assigned to it. Backend you should be expecting an "email" parameter with a value not "request.params" as you state in your question. Can you show your backend code?

Comment: @papakia Yes. You are right. I misunderstood the format. Is there a way I can get the email in a format that allows me to fetch it as `request.params` or `request.headers` or `request.body` (although I don't want `request.body` since it is a `GET` request).

I have also edited the question and added my backend code.

Comment: Are you using Express? If so then see the answer posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9243020/3453034

Comment: @papakia Thanks, I guess this should solve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the params to send data. Instead, use data itself

```
$http({
    url: 'api/me', 
    method: "GET",
    data: {email: email}
});
```

and then in the back end:

```
User.findOne({ email: request.email }, function(error, user) ...
```