# Angularjs Post request to server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

How would i gather that info im sending from the client? in this case, the id?

How can I get the id?

I do use client sided request:

```
    return $http.post('/api/kill', {id:4}, {
              headers: {}
            })
```

and when i check server sided for req.body `console.log(Req.body)` i do get:

```
 { '{"id":4}': '' }
```

req.body.id returns:

```
undefined
```

How can i get the id of 4?

EDIT1:

the main code is located at https://github.com/meanjs/mean

server sided code:

```
app.post('/api/kill', function (req, res) {


        console.log(req.body); // { '{"id":4}': '' }
        console.log(req.body.id); // undefined

    });
```

Comment: It seems like your server is sending the data back incorrectly

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. How would what be? Are you asking how, or are you not sure how it's possible?

Comment: @ExplosionPills  im asking how to fix it

Comment: The server is sending back content with a property of `{"id":4}` that has no value. I would have to see the server code

Comment: The server code is there, I'm only outputting the result of req.body

Comment: Have you tried JSON.stringify()-ing the properties you wish to send to the server?  It looks like it is taking your object, converting it to a string and attempting to use that as the key.

Maybe something like `return $http.post('/api/kill', JSON.stringify({id:4})...`

Comment: what does this log?  `$http.post( '/api/kill', { id:4 }, { headers:{}}).then( function( rsp ){ console.log( 'rsp', rsp )})`

Comment: Are you using express? If yes then do you have body-parser installed? https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Comment: @DawidWiniarczyk yes. and yes.

Comment: Can you check your browsers network tab and tell us the outgoing data. Is it the correct JSON-Object? Is the content-type application/json?

Comment: Would be easier to identify the problem if we saw some of the server side code too.

Comment: chat anyone? ( btw, editing the question now in a min)

Comment: Posting primitive type is has this issue in WebApi(.Net REST), may be its the same here.could you try $http.post('/api/kill', '"4"');   Another way to pass a primitive type is to pass it as query string 'api/kill?id=4' - just my 2 cents;may be its whole different with node.js

Comment: @Developer if i did api/kill?id=4, how would i retrieve it?

Comment: you gotta read it from query string

Comment: how do i do that with mean / express @Developer ?

Comment: I might be saying something stupid here as my experience with node is very minimal.  this might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-express-js-on-node-js``.

Answer (score 4):

You need to assign that `id` property to an object like

`item = { id : 4 }`

Lets suppose you have a `text-box` and the user wants to save a new item by inserting its name in it and click on submit.

Lets also suppose you are using a `MongoDB` collection of items, which have only `id` field for simplicity.

Here's what you should do to get it going easy.

Make sure you are importing `bodyParser`

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
```

**HTML - saving a new item with custom id**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="id">ID</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" ng-model="ItemController.formData.id">
</div>

<button type="submit" ng-click="ItemController.createItem()" >Submit</button>
```

**Angular part - ItemController.js**

```
'use strict';

angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('ItemController', ItemController);

function ItemController($http) {

  var vm = this;

  /** Creates a New Marker on submit **/
  vm.createItem = function() {

          // Grabs all of the text box fields
          var itemData = {
              id        : vm.formData.id
          };

          // Saves item data to the db
          $http.post('/api/kill', itemData)
              .success(function(response) {
                if(response.err){
                  console.log('Error: ' + response.err);
                } else {
                  console.log('Saved '+response);
                }
              });
   };
}
```

**Route Handling - routes.js**

```
var ItemFactory   = require('./factories/item.factory.js');

// Opens App Routes
module.exports = function(app) {

    /** Posting a new Item **/
    app.post('/api/kill', function(req, res) {
        ItemFactory.postItem(req).then( function (item) {
          return res.json(item);
        });
    });

};
```

**Post into MongoDB - item.factory.js**

```
var Item  = require('../models/item-model');
exports.postItem = postItem;

function postItem(item) {
    return new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {  
        var newItem = new Item(item.body);
        newItem.save(function(err) {
            if (err){
                return reject({err : 'Error while saving item'});
            }
            // If no errors are found, it responds with a JSON of the new item
            return resolve(item.body);
        });
    });
}
```

If you try `console.log()` on the different pieces of code where I passed the item, you can properly see an object with `id property`.

I hope I've been helpful.

Comment: Will accept the answer soon. Is it possible to chat with you? i have some few other questions too.

Comment: where could we take a chat @andreaM16?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121999/angularjs-post-request-to-server

Comment: are you online @andreaM16 ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39193041/return-resolve-error-in-node-function @andreaM16

Answer (score 2):

you miss the single quote :

```
var obj = { 'id':4 };
console.log(obj.id); //display 4
```

in your example :

```
 return $http.post('/api/kill', {'id':4}, {
      headers: {}
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

response you are getting is not in object form

```
 { '{"id":4}': '' }
```

it is a key value pair and key is a string

```
'{"id":4}'
```

In order to get the right value at your end your json response shoulb be like

```
{ { 'id':4 } }
```

and then it will work like

```
    console.log(req.body); // { {"id":4} }
    console.log(req.body.id); // 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you enabled JSON body parser in your node.js application.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
....
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```