# return resolve error in node function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

Why wont usernametoid function return the acual id? cause im trying to send the result of the userdata as the return. In this case, i want to only send the userdata`s _id attribute. but it seems like it wont work.

```
console.log(userdata._id); // works
        return resolve(userdata._id); // wont work.
```

output of variable userdata:

```
  {
      cash: 7300002,
      bank: 0,
      xp: 0,
      rank: 1,
      points: 1,
      location: 1,
      health: 100,
      protection: 1,
      attack: 1,
      family: '0',
      password: 'jKa4qC7pRCgE5jvzD9Vv1pRUNxFlQEM7Jpq/IoJ/sUWOAv1Wx1RI/j/Vu6Zf8zyNkCFcg3QBtdfAC+lmPS8KIA==',
      profileImageURL: 'modules/users/client/img/profile/default.png',
      roles: [ 'user' ],
      created: Sat Aug 27 2016 12:33:55 GMT-0400 (EDT),
      __v: 0,
      username: 'signature',
      provider: 'local',
      salt: '4ySlrr9ggESxBB3dR5bx4Q==',
      _id: 57c1c0f3b6b20c011242bf22 }
```

when i do: `return resolve(userdata._id) it would get this error:

```
/server/factory/user_factory.js:52
                return resolve(userdata._id);
                                       ^

    TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of null
```

node.js call:

```
var articles = require('../controllers/articles.server.controller'),
    path = require('path'),
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Article = mongoose.model('Article'),
    Users = mongoose.model('User'),
  errorHandler = require(path.resolve('./modules/core/server/controllers/errors.server.controller'));


var userFunc   = require('../factory/user_factory.js');
    app.post('/api/kill', function (req, res) {

        console.log("starting");
        var username = "signature";//req.query.username;

        var result = ["test service"];

        var data = req.user;
        userFunc.usernametoid(username).then( function (otherplayerid) {


            if (!(otherplayerid)) {
                console.log("other player is acually " + otherplayerid);
                result.push("denne brukeren finnes ikke! " + otherplayerid);

            } else {

                userFunc.usernametoid(otherplayerid).then( function (otherplayer) {
                    if (data.location != otherplayer.location) {
                        result.push("Du er ikke i samme lokasjon som " + username);
                        result.push(data.location + " vs " + otherplayer.location);
                    } else {

                        userFunc.addCash(req.user._id,100000);
                        result.push("starter lokasjonisering");

                    }
                });
            }
            res.json(result);
        });

});
```

user factory:

```
var articles = require('../controllers/articles.server.controller'),
    path = require('path'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Article = mongoose.model('Article'),
    Users = mongoose.model('User'),
    errorHandler = require(path.resolve('./modules/core/server/controllers/errors.server.controller'));




exports.usernametoid = usernametoid;

    function usernametoid(id) {

    return new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {
        var query = Users.findOne( { username : id } );

        //  var query = Users.find({_id:id});
        query.exec(function(err, userdata) {
            if (err){
                return reject({err : 'Error while getting user info'});
            }


            console.log(userdata._id);
            return resolve(userdata);
        });

    }, function (){
        return reject({err : 'error while fetching cash'});
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are not passing correctly the fetched user to the `query.exec`.

You need to do:

```
var Users  = require('../models/users-model.js');

function usernametoid(id) {
    return new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {
        Users.findOne({ username : id }).then( function(user){
          //If you use lodash you can do _.isNull(user)
          if(user == null){
            return reject({error : 'User not found'});
          }

          user.exec(function(userdata, error) {
              if(userdata){
                return resolve(userdata);
              } 
              if(error){
                 return reject({error : 'Error while executing query'});
              }
           });
        });
    });
}
```

I don't really get why you are importing `Users Model` like that. I do not think `Node` will be able to fetch it like that.

And, you should require `mongoose` in your `server.js`

To catch the rejection you need the following code:

```
UserFactory.userNameToId(id).then( function(response){
  if(response.error){
    console.log('error '+response.error);
  }
  if(response){
    console.log('Got response '+response);
  }
});
```

Comment: that seems right, but for some reason i still dnt get it to work. after the user.exec

Comment: What does `console.log(userdata);` gives you before the resolve?

Comment: Nothing seems like IT wont execute

Comment: `console.log(user);` after the then?

Comment: the same as my output of variable userdata: chat?

Comment: made it work.  removed all      user.exec(function(userdata, error) {. how can i catch the resolve rejection ? to for example send a message to the client again?

Comment: im still having trouble @andreaM16 :|

Comment: To call The error, IT need to be resolved aswell and not rejected

Comment: Now you should catch it

Comment: can we chat please?

Comment: Hi, I'm off right now. I'll poke you tomorrow around 11 cest

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121999/angularjs-post-request-to-server