# How to call function using MEAN technology

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, mean

I am working with MEAN technology and  I want to call the function Using the

**Controller.js** of the client side, I am define the anchor tag on the header and

call the link Which is define into the **module.js** I want to call the function

But I don't know how to define the function.

I given the link into the header using:-

```
                  <li><a href="#/commentData">comment</a></li>
```

Now here is my **module.js**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",['ngRoute','ngStorage']);
app.config(function($routeProvider){
 $routeProvider.
 when('/commentData',{
 controller: 'ticketcontroller',

 }).
 otherwise({
     redirectTo:'/'
     });
});
```

I want to define the function after defined the controller how can I do it.Please help me.

Comment: so you want to run a function  in ticketcontroller.js when the page loads ??

Comment: no actually I want to call function when I click the link

Comment: $routeProvider.
 when('/commentData',{
 controller: 'ticketcontroller', can we write the function after this line 

 }).

Comment: no you cant write here,config section is for only for configuring our views

Comment: If you want to call a `function` in `AngularJS` that communicates with the back-end in `Node` take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107564/angularjs-post-request-to-server/39181250#39181250