# How to find documents in database using query string

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to find documents in my database using a query string:

```
app.get('/', (request, response) => {
  db.collection('mycollection').find(req.query).toArray((error, results) => {
    console.log(response)
  })
})
```

The request looks like this:

```
{ userName: 'K Moe' }
```

And the error I get is:

```
MongoError: query selector must be an object
```

I've tried changing req.query to `req.query.userName` and `req.query['userName']` but that doesn't help...

Comment: it may be a typo...but it should be `request.query` instead of `req.query`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing
req.query from `{ userName: 'K Moe' }` to `{ 'userName': 'k Moe' }`

Comment: The request is made using a query string url. How can I do that?

Comment: To use query params follow this link for nodejs + express:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-express-js-on-node-js

Store the value of the username into a variable ParamVarHere
`var ParamVarHere = req.params.username`

When you get the value of your parameter, change the mongodb method to do the following:
`db.collection('mycollection').find({'userName': ParamVarHere }).toArray((error, results) => {
    console.log(response)
});`

Comment: Please let me know if this is still an issue and I will write some sample code for you to download for express + mongo integration