# How to pass the ajax get request data to nodejs GET route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

This is my ajax request call

```
  $.ajax({
    url: '/refresh',
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: {
        Name: $("#inputName").val(),
        Url: $("#inputUrl").val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('form submitted.' + data);
    }
  });
```

This is the GET route in nodejs

```
app.get('/refresh', function(req, res) {
            console.log("My data" + JSON.stringify(req.body));
            //other operations
        }
```

How can i get the data which is passed from ajax call in my js?? Please help!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Comment: You are making a GET request, there is no request body to describe the content type of. Claiming the requests's content type is JSON is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery's `.ajax()` method sends the `data` property as a query string for GET requests, so in your Express code you have to retrieve that data from `req.query` instead of from `req.body`.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [req.query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-express-js-on-node-js) for that:

```
const id = req.query._some_query_param; // $_GET["id"]

// Sample URL: https://foo.bar/items?id=234
app.get("/items",function(req,res){
   const id = req.query.id;
   //further operations to perform
});
```

If you want to get the route parameters you could use [req.params](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params) which only gets the route parameters and not the query string parameters.

For example:

```
// Sample URL: https://foo.bar/items/322
app.get("items/:id",function(req,res){
 const id = req.params.id;
 //further operations to perform
});
```