# Express server route format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I have two different types of possible API class I can make. 
The first one is:

```
http://api_url.com/api/v1/schools/countries/BR
```

and the second one is:

```
http://api_url.com/api/v1/schools/countries/BR?admin1=MA
```

My route in backend/routes/schools.js is:

```
router.get('/countries/:country', forward_get);

  const forward_get = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req);
  const url = `${url}${req.originalUrl}`
  getResponse(url, acToken, res);
}
```

How do I make it so that I am able to also make the second api call and get the appropriate parameters "admin1: MA". Ive gone through the whole req object and I don't seem to find them anywhere. So far I've been able to make the first api call without a problem.

Comment: Have you looked in the [`req.url`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6912872/691711) object?

Answer (score 1):

This is the only route you need:

You access `admin1` using `req.query.admin1`

and

You access `country` using `req.params.country`