# Parameter restriction with Node.js

Tags: node.js

What I want to do is check the script URL for a parameter & display the content of that parameter like:

`www.mywebsite.com/mynodescript.js?parameter=i+am+new+to+node!`

Now I want to display "I am new to node!" on browser screen and if the parameter is not present I just want to exit.

edit:
I found this code but I am not sure how to deploy it

```
var url = require('url');
var url_parts = url.parse(request.url, true);
var query = url_parts.query;
```

Note: i want to upload my script on heroku & want it to call it remotely

Comment: Also see this question which is very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-express-js-on-node-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say you don't know how to deploy it, I'm assuming you don't have a http server setup yet?

Look at using Express (http://expressjs.com/). It's easy enough to get started with.

Create a file called `app.js` like this:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

// This handles the path /mynodescript.js You can create a bunch of functions like this to handle different paths. See the express docs for more.
app.get('/mynodescript.js', (req, res)=>{
  let parameter = req.query.parameter; // <-- Could also do let {parameter} = req.query This is where you would pull out your url parameters
  if(parameter){
    res.send(parameter); // <-- this sends it back to the browser.
  }else{
    res.status(422).end(); // <-- you can set a status here or send an error message or something useful.
  }
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

Start the script using `node app.js` from the same directory.

Then open a browser and go to `http://localhost:3000/mynodescript.js?parameter=i+am+new+to+node` and you should see your parameter

Note that you will have to install express first `npm install express --save`

Note that you do not have to use express. There are quite a few http libraries available for nodejs. Or you can use the built-in http server (https://nodejs.org/api/http.html). It's good to get familiar with the NodeJS docs, but their http server is cumbersome to work with.

Comment: thanks :)
it worked when i tried it locally
but when i uploaded it on a server of heroku it is crashing
i want to host it online so that i access it with browser

Comment: what i want is something like this 

[code]
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

  parameter = req.query.parameter; 
  if(parameter){
    res.send(parameter); 
  }else{
    res.status(422).end(); 
  }
[/code]
but it is not working can you fix it ?
the server i am hosting script on will make script run on server 
so i just want to check for requested url

Comment: if you are deploying to heroku do not provide the port, instead use **process.env.PORT**

Comment: thanks it really helped
i just read some docs & achieved what i wanted :D