# Modifying query string to support parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the route,

```
app.get("/employees", (req, res) => {
    data.getAllEmployees().then((data) => {
        res.json(data);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log("An error was encountered: " + err);
    });
});
```

And I need to support queries such as `/employees?status=value` and `/employees?department=value`

I've created these functions in `data-service.js`

```
module.exports.getEmployeesByStatus = function(status) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (employees.length == 0) {
            reject("No results");
        } else {
            resolve(employees.status == status);
        }
    });
}
module.exports.getEmployeesByDepartment = function(department) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (employees.length == 0) {
            reject("No results");
        } else {
            resolve(employees.department == department);
        }
    });
}
```

How do I properly call these functions from within my `GET/employees` route? Im not sure where I should be specifying those queries. I reckon there must be an `IF/ELSE` statement somewhere, but my `app.get` route specifies `app.get("/employees", ...`. Where do I add the `IF/ELSE`?

Comment: Are you asking how do you read the querystring parameters?

Comment: It seems so, I found this resource just now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-express-js-on-node-js

Comment: But how do I modify my already-existing `/employees` route to support this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create another handler for the "employees" path and then, you would need to check if a query string is available by using [request.query](http://expressjs.com/de/api.html#req.query), that returns an object with params from query string, and check what action should be taken from there.

something similar to:

```
app.get("/employees", (req, res) => {

    if(req.query.department)
         getEmployeesByStatus(req.query.department);
    else if(req.query.status)
        //and so on

});
```

also, you could set up a function called filter for instance, pass req.query as parameter and filter accordingly.. something like:

```
app.get("/employees", (req, res) => {

    if(!_.isEmpty(req.query))
        myService.filter(req.query);    
});
```

Comment: My `getEmployeesByManager()` for reference: https://pastebin.com/4UDW5PLS

Comment: it says your link has been removed

Comment: Apologies: https://pastebin.com/0MGjDzAJ (disregard the `err ||` on lines 25 and 34)