# Pass data using question mark in node.js

Tags: node.js, api, get

I want to pass data from `.ejs` to my node API. For `edit` a record I'm passing id of the data.

For that I'm usign `click` event like this.

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Edit" onclick="edit(<%= data[i].id %>)">
```

And I create a function in `<script>` tag.

```
function edit(id){
     alert(id);
     window.location.replace('/bill/edit?id='+id);
}
```

And my API is this.

```
router.get('/edit/:id', function (req, res, next) {
     console.log("Id is : " , req.query.id);
}
```

As per I used to before it's right I have search also on it. And it all shows this way but I don't understand that why it's not work for me.

When I run API in `postman` I got 404 Error.

```
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<h2>404</h2>
<pre>Error: Not Found
at E:\myapp\app.js:30:13
```

Comment: Your router should be `/edit` instead of `/edit/:id`

Comment: yaaa thanks it works for me... Thank you . I was think that I want to pass id so I have to set `/edit/:id` but I was wrong ... Thanks again @vibhor1997a

Comment: I was follow by this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-express-js-on-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

Your API is '**/edit/:id**' but you are hitting '**/bill/edit?**'. May be that's why the you aren't able to pass the data to your API as they aren't same. Also, check the API endpoint once.