# Node - ExpressJS - How to see all parameters and values from URL request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have Node / Express code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.listen(port);
console.log('Server started! At http://localhost:' + port);

app.get('/api/users', function(req, res) {

    var user_id = req.param('id');
    console.log(user_id);

    res.send(user_id );
});
```

When I got to URL in browser (or curl) to `http://localhost:8080/api/users?id=4` - output is 4.

How to see any parameter and value that user might enter?
e.g. if someone enters: `http://localhost:8080/api/users?par1=123&par2=321` it should return `par1 = 123` and `par2 = 321` etc.

Comment: You could also use the technique shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-express-js-on-node-js) answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `query` param of request:

```
console.log(req.query);
```

It will contain an object

```
{
  par1: '123',
  par2: '321'
}
```