# How to get value of URL parameter in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parameters

For example I have this URL: `http://localhost/chat.html?channel=talk`
How can I get the value of parameter `channel` in Node.js?
I want to store the value of `channel` in a variable.

I changed server.get to this:

```
server.get("/channel", (req, res) => {
    let query = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
    console.log(req.query.channel);
    let rueckgabe = {
        channel: req.query.channel
    };
    res.send(JSON.stringify(rueckgabe));
});
```

Now I'm expecting an output of the value of `channel` on my console but nothing appears.

This is the full code of `index.js`:

```
//Server erstellen
const express = require("express");
let server = express();
server.use(express.static("public"));

//Socket.io
const http = require("http");
let httpServer = http.Server(server);
const socketIo = require("socket.io");
let io = socketIo(httpServer);

//Eventlistener bei Verbindungsaufbau
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log(socket.id);

    socket.on("chatnachricht", eingabe => {
        io.emit("nachricht", eingabe);
    });
});

let stdIn = process.openStdin();
stdIn.addListener("data", (eingabe) => {
    io.emit("nachricht", eingabe.toString());
});

server.get("/channel", (req, res) => {
    let query = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
    console.log(query);
    let rueckgabe = {
        channel: query.channel
    };
    //res.send(JSON.stringify(rueckgabe));
    res.send(JSON.stringify(rueckgabe));
});

httpServer.listen(80, () => {
    console.log("Server läuft");
});
```

## SOLUTION

This code works so far but with limitations:

```
//Server erstellen
const express = require("express");
let server = express();
server.use(express.static("public"));

const http = require("http");
let httpServer = http.Server(server);
const socketIo = require("socket.io");
let io = socketIo(httpServer);
var router = express.Router();
const url = require("url");
var path = require('path');


//Eventlistener bei Verbindungsaufbau
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log(socket.id);

    socket.on("chatnachricht", eingabe => {
        io.emit("nachricht", eingabe);
    });
});

/*
let stdIn = process.openStdin();
stdIn.addListener("data", (eingabe) => {
    io.emit("nachricht", eingabe.toString());
});
*/

server.get("/chat", (req, res) => {
    let query = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
    console.log(query.channel);
    let rueckgabe = {
        channel: query.channel
    };
    res.sendFile('chat.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, 'public/') });
    //res.send(JSON.stringify(rueckgabe));
});

httpServer.listen(80, () => {
    console.log("Server läuft");
});
```

Now it works with `server.get()` but I can't use both `res.sendFile('chat.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, 'public/') });` and `res.send(JSON.stringify(rueckgabe));`. How can I use both?

Comment: It's not clear what `server` is. Are you using `express` or is this something else?

Comment: are you using expressjs or native http module of nodejs?

Comment: Yes I'm using express

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get GET (query string) variables in Express.js on Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-express-js-on-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the Express framework for Node.

[From the docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query), query string params may be accessed via `req.query`:

```
server.get("/channel", (req, res) => {
    let id = req.query.id; // where "id" is a paramter on the query string
}
```

And if you need the full URL of the request:

```
server.get("/channel", (req, res) => {
    let fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;
}
```

Comment: `server.get("/channel", (req, res) => {
    let id = req.query.id; // $_GET["id"]
}` This is not working for me.

Comment: @123php Sounds like your query string parameters may be malformed or missing. Also, you do have change `id` to match the actual parameters used in your query string -- `id` is just an example.

Comment: See my start post

Comment: Sorry but `console.log(req.query.channel);` doesn't appear in my console. I have edited my start post, look at it again.

Comment: @123php Yes, you need to replace `id` with the actual query string parameter in your requests. Try using `req.query.channel`.

Comment: I did and it's not working. :( There is no output on my console.

Answer (score 0):

Well you mentioned for this url `http://localhost/chat.html?channel=talk` you're not seeing the channel parameter in the server. That's because you aren't hitting the endpoint that you've defined.

> Copy of your code from above

```
server.get("/channel", (req, res) => {
    let query = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
    console.log(req.query.channel);
    let rueckgabe = {
        channel: req.query.channel
    };
    res.send(JSON.stringify(rueckgabe));
});
```

You're setting the `/channel` url here. With this configuration if you want to get the query parameter you need to call `http://localhost:{portnumber}/channel?channel=somerandomvalue`

If you want to have the `/chat` url change your configuration like this:

```
server.get("/chat", (req, res) => {
    let query = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
    console.log(req.query.channel);
    let rueckgabe = {
        channel: req.query.channel
    };
    res.send(JSON.stringify(rueckgabe));
});
```

and call into `http://localhost:{portnumber}/chat?channel=somerandomvalue`

If you want to serve a static html while using the url name as the same file name you can do something like this:

```
var router = express.Router();
var path = require('path');

router.get('/chat', function(req, res) {
    // where chat.html is in the public directory
    console.log(req.query.channel);
    res.sendFile('chat.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, '../public/') });
});
```

Comment: Yes I understand. I have `chat.html`, you didn't mention `chat.html` in your URLs. If I call this URL `http://localhost:{portnumber}/chat?channel=somerandomvalue` I'll get an error because `chat.html` is missing.

Comment: You might need to update the /chat with /chat.html then - are you trying to serve a static html page?

Comment: I‘m serving a static `html` page with `JavaScript` code

Comment: If you want to have a back-end code, serving static html is probably not a very good idea. Still - if you want to send a regular html (for now) you can use res.sendFile() - Example here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-expressjs-to-deliver-html-files

Comment: To explain this a bit more - the expectation would be to have the url like /chat - but when the user hits /chat url your server would send the static HTML file. All the other stuff (parameters etc...) would be handled in the server side.

Comment: I want the URL to be chat.html?channel=talk or /chat?channel=talk and I want to serve chat.html. How can I get this running?

Comment: In PHP it‘s just so easy.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Is `router` a module?

Comment: Updated my answer again. This should work with /chat?channel=talk

Comment: Changed it to: `router.get("/chat.html", (req, res) => {
 let query = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
 console.log(req.query.channel);
 let rueckgabe = {
  channel: req.query.channel
 };
    res.sendFile('public/chat.html');
 res.send(JSON.stringify(rueckgabe));
});` Doesn't work, still no output on my console. This is the URL: `http://localhost/chat.html?channel=talk`

Comment: Can you change it to /chat please? - and I've updated the code

Comment: I changed it to /chat and now I get an error: `Cannot GET /chat`

Comment: Yes I did. You mean this: `res.sendFile('chat.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, '../public/') });`

Comment: yes? Please make sure the about this part: router.get('/chat'

Comment: I've added the printing of the parameter as well. This should work - I have it working here.

Comment: For me it's not working. This is the code I have so far: `router.get("/chat", (req, res) => {
 //let query = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
 console.log(req.query.channel);
 let rueckgabe = {
  channel: req.query.channel
 };
    res.sendFile('public/chat.html');
 res.send(JSON.stringify(rueckgabe));
});` index.js is in folder websockets and inside of websockets there is a folder public with chat.html inside.

Comment: I'll ask my teacher tomorrow. :/ But thank you for your help. I appreciate it. :)

Comment: I got it working but with limitations, see my code in my start post. Maybe you have an idea?

Comment: You can’t use both. You are sending only one response which is the html, you can’t send both the html and the json as separate responses to the same request