# How to handle req.params.url when url contains "://"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to write a program using ExpressJS.
The user should be able to send me an url. But there is an issue.
It doesn't work because the user send me the url with an url (using XMLHTTPRequest).

How can I handle urls and get methods which contain an url ?
Thank you

Comment: What do you mean *"send me the url with an url"*?!

Comment: can you give the url you are trying to solve?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. There's nothing about the characters `://` which prevent them being sent through most of the common ways that use HTTP.

Comment: The user will send to the server something like that : 
website.com/create/https://www.google.com

But there is an issue, because the "https://www.google.com" parameter contains "://"

Comment: Do you mean using a path parameter like /submitUrl/:url ? Have you tried using escaped query parameters?

Comment: @moronatorYes I mean that.
How to do an escaped query parameters ?

Comment: The client needs to URL escape everything they're putting in the URL.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ok but how to do that ?

Comment: Read the docs for whatever client you're using. My point is it's not Express's job.

Comment: @Des2207 tried the solution proposed in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use query parameters instead of url parameters.
This would look like so:

```
http://youhosthere.com/submitUrl/?url=THE_URL_TO_SUBMIT
```

However this also means, the user has to escape the url he wants to submit. In Javascript for example this can be done by using `encodeURIComponent`:

```
encodeURIComponent('THE_URL_TO_SUBMIT')
```

For further information on encodeURIComponent, you may want to read [the mozilla article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

With express you can read the query params using `req.query.YOUR_QUERY_PARAM` as proposed by Marcus Granström [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-express-js-on-node-js)