# When an object is sent along with a get/post request express returns an empty object for req.body

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

When I send an object as a parameter of my post or get request express doesn't seem to receive it

I have tried get and post requests both on the front end and on the server. All the dependencies are working fine (body-parser, etc.)

front end:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:4000/videoComments/comment', {pauseTime: 10})
```

or

```
axios.get('http://localhost:4000/videoComments/comment', {data:{pauseTime: 10}})
```

back-end:

```
videoCommentsRoutes.route('/comment').get(function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
```

req.body is an empty object. req.data, req.params are all undefined

Comment: Try calling like this `axios.get('http://localhost:4000/videoComments/comment', {params:{pauseTime: 10}})`. You can access params at server by `req.params`

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-express-js-on-node-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GET` request supports only query parameters. `axios` (as well as any of `fetch` or `XMLHTTPRequest` wrappers, such as `superagent`) should transform your object into query string.

Try using `req.query` to get the query parameters.
Here is `express` [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query) about it.

Answer (score 0):

Back-End should be like

```
videoCommentsRoutes.route('/comment/:pauseTime').get(function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.pauseTime);
})
```

or

```
videoCommentsRoutes.route('/comment').get(function (req, res) {
        console.log(req.query.pauseTime);
    })
```

Front-end Call like

```
axios.get('http://localhost:4000/videoComments/comment', {params:{pauseTime: 10}})
```