# How to get params from url in angular and express?

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I have a URL which looks like `http://www.example.com/idf34he8sf/9iad2hf7usnf`. I want to get the params `idf34he8sf` and `9iad2hf7usnf`

I have used below code

In angular

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.organizationId = params.get("organizationId");
      this.embedId= params.get("embedId"); 
}
```

In Node

```
req.params
```

and

```
req.originalUrl
```

I want to get the params `idf34he8sf` and `9iad2hf7usnf`

Comment: r u want to get params in node ?

Comment: Which version of Angular are U  using?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to get GET (query string) variables in Express.js on Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-express-js-on-node-js)

Comment: @SaurabhMistry I need to get params in node and as well as angular.

Comment: @Mohit I'm using Angular7.

Comment: @Ram you can use `ActivatedRoute` to fetch params in angular and  for nodejs you will need to declare parameterised routes and use them with `req.params` or if you want to fetch query string then use `req.query`. Provided the sample code in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define params in your api as-

```
example/:organizationId/:embedId
```

then fetch these params using-

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
  this.organizationId = this.router.snapshots.params['organizationId']
  this.embedId = this.router.snapshots.params['embedId']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Node knows nothing about Angular, you will need to design your API to take those paramaters and pass them when calling the API.

Comment: I'm using the same URL to get params in Angular and node independently. I'm able to get queryParams but not individual params.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @angular/router

`import { Router } from '@angular/router';`

Define a variable to hold URL

```
 href:string;
params:string[];
```

Then in Constructor

```
 constructor(private router: Router) {
```

}

In ngOnInit

```
this.href = this.router.url;
    this.params = this.href.split('/');
```

Answer (score 0):

In angular you can use ActivatedRoute to fetch params from the URL

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

constructor(route: ActivatedRoute){}

/* Do Something*/

public someFunction(){
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
             /* use Params*/   
    }
}
```

In NodeJS you will need to add while declaring your routes as shown below:

```
router.get('/:id', (req,res) =>{
   let id = req.params; // for parameterised routes
   // fetching query string  use below:
   // region = req.query.region;
   return res.json(id); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //import the ActivatedRoute to use route.snapshot.params
    

    import { ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';


     //define  a variable to store the param from url 
     
     public param:any;         

    //And in constructor create a instance of ActivatedRoute
    

    constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute,) {}

    //Then in ngOnInit
    ngOnInit(): void {
    
      this.param = this.route.snapshot.params["Your-params-name in url)"];
       // params-name means (/:id/)
      //this will store the params from your url to the variable param (public)
    }
    
    
     
    //in my url is I wanted to store specific id of a book
    // from url localhost:4200/books/60ab539f678gfraep/  
    // I used  
    {path: 'books/:id',component: showBookComponent},
    //in my ROUTING MODULE  
    //so I gave above code as 
    public Id:string;
     ngOnInit():void {
    // this.Id = route.snapshot.params['id'];

    }
```

Comment: Please do not code dump. Please explain your answer as it will help others.

Comment: i edited my code Dath Vader to make understandable to any one