# URL parse returns null or []

Tags: node.js

I am trying to parse a URL and I am returning []. How do I format my simplified query to grab the ID from the URL?

```
const url = require('url');

const apURL = new URL('https://local.apex.json/user/11225');
const search_params = current_url.searchParams;

const id = search_params.get('id');


console.log(id);
```

Comment: What is current_url? Same as apURL? That doesn't *have* any search params.

Comment: A url parameter named `id` takes the form of `?id=11225`, as in * https://local.apex.json/user?id=11225`. You're looking for something different.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to parse the url? If so, this will work

const url = require('url');

pathString = url.parse('https://local.apex.json/user/11225').path;

console.log('Full path', pathString);

splitPathString = pathString.split('/');

console.log('After split ', splitPathString);

console.log('Get a specific array item post split ', splitPathString[2]);

Console results as below,
Full path /user/11225

After split  [ '', 'user', '11225' ]

Get a specific array item post split  11225

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I may have asked the question incorrectly. https://local.apex.json/user/11225 contains a Json object from a database. The items include  userID, user_name, user_email, api_name, api_token. I need to grab the api username and api token. My apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse de url. Yo do not need to do `new URL('https://local.apex.json/user/11225')`.

You only need to do this:

```
var url = require('url');
var url_parts = url.parse("https://local.apex.json/user/11225", true);
var query = url_parts.query;
```

Here is the full answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6912872/5854328