# querying mongoose letter by letter

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to build a search system for a social media application, where people can find users but I want it to be that if the user is typing a word, the search starts and the more words the user inputs the more the searches become better.

***For example***: If I type `p...` in the database it shows all the users that start with `p`, then if I type in a the db shows all the users that start with `pa...` and so on, is there a method like that for `mongoose` or do I have to use the front end to make that happen?
 Btw I am using `React`

Comment: What is your backend application made of? Node-express.js?

Comment: it is made with both express and node

Answer (score 0):

You could probably write a mongo regex query to get this done!

```
db.getCollection('fruits').find({'fruit_name': { $regex: 'Apple', $options: 'i'}})
```

option `i`  performs a case insensitive search. Call the search endpoint on every onChange of the input search field.

Comment: sorry please i do not understand please could you elaborate?

Comment: So you must have exposed an endpoint for search right? Add the MongoDB regex query that I have shown you in my answer to that endpoint!  Instead of `Apple` put the variable with the search string and you 'll get the results. Modify the collection name and search field accordingly !

Comment: yes i understand that part, i meant how do i implement this in react frontend, so for every text in my input it searches the db

Comment: Example before i click the search button, and i type P into the seacrh box, it should already be looking for users starting with p

Comment: Yes,  hit the api for every change event triggered in react ! If need more help with React can you please post the REACT Code in the question?

Answer (score 0):

I will divide the solution into two parts :

**Front-end** :

you can send the data as a query string , for example :

user type : p..  , request must be like this :

```
let search='p..';
example.com?search=search
```

**Back-end** :
this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6912872/8945943) show you how you can read a query string ;

now , i will use this query to find the result in my mongo collection
Example :

```
var query = url_parts.query // my-query; 
db.users.find({"name": /.*query.*/})
```

**Note**  : I suppose you have some knowledge of HTTP REQUESTS ,NodeJs that to understand what i said