# How to filter mongoDB in NodeJS API, checking if values are included in objects in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, filter, find, rest

I am writing REST API in NodeJS with MongoDB. Structure of the database is:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "12345",
        "name": "Meal name",
        "category": "dessert",
        "area": "british",
        "imageUrl": "https.image.jpg",
        "instructions": "some instructions...",
        "ingredients": [
            {
                "name": "salt",
                "measure": "1g"
            },
            {
                "name": "chicken",
                "measure": "1"
            },
            {
                "name": "butter",
                "measure": "90g"
            }, ...
        ]
    }, ...
]
```

I can write a route to get data which meet one condition,
i.e.:

```
//getting all, when category = :category
router.get('/meals/category=:category', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const meals = await Meal.find({category: req.params.category})
    res.json(meals)

  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: err.message })
  }
})
```

Here, route

> 'meals/category=vegetarian'

get all data with category = vegetarian.

However, I want to have route, which will filter all data by parameters: category, area, ingredients.
For example:

> meals/ingredients=salt,pepper&category=dessert&area=american

should return all data, which contains salt and pepper in array, and category = dessert.

another example:

> meals/area=american&category=dessert

should return all data, where area=american and category=dessert

How can I write the router.get() method to achieve that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You're probably looking to implement Query Parameters (meaning the syntax will be slightly different, instead your example call will look like `meals?area=american&category=dessert` (this is the industry standard so it's better to get used to it as soon as possible).

This StackOverflow post describes how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-express-js-on-node-js