# How to fix "window is not defined error" in js

Tags: javascript

This is my current code:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
module.exports = (req, res) => {
    
    res.send({
        creatorid: "",
        whitelisted: false
    })
}
```

At the moment, it is giving me the error: `window is not defined.` I have no idea why. Can someone help please?

Comment: There is no `window` object in a node environment.

Comment: How can I bypass that and get the Params then?

Comment: It might depend on your framework, but most probably they're stored in the `req` parameter. That is, if the request is made to the right endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned above. There is no window object in Node enviroment.

If you are using Express

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('id: ' + req.query.id);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Also check out [this](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_url) and [this thred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-express-js-on-node-js)