# How to write an API route with query string parameters in Express.js

Tags: javascript, express-router

Trying to write a simple route, getting a record by it's id property/column

```
const router = require("express").Router();    
router.get("/record/:id", getRecordById)    // CHANGE HERE
```

This is how I'm able to use for frontend ajax -

```
http://localhost:3001/record/1
```

What do I need to change, to be able to use the route as

```
http://localhost:3001/?record=1
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-express-js-on-node-js)

Comment: {your_domain}/record?id=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a route like this.

```
router.get("/", function (req, res) {
  // Get record id
  const record_id = req.query.record;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case

API:
router.get("/record", getRecordById)

URL:
http://localhost:3001/record?id=1

Get the query string in api:
req.query.id