# Express endpoint not matched when passing query params

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, curl

I have a very simple express API:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('in root!')
})

app.get('/hello', (req, res) => {
  res.send('in hello! req.query.id is ' + req.query.id)
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Hitting it with CURLs:

```
curl http://localhost:3000/hello
```

Result is:

```
in hello! req.query.id is undefined
```

Which is correct. Now I run:

```
curl http://localhost:3000/hello?id=123
```

Hey presto, I get:

```
no matches found: http://localhost:3000/hello?id=123
```

According to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6913287/1246159) it really should be as simple as adding "?id=123" to the URL, but somehow I've made a mistake somewhere because now the endpoint is not matched...

Im using express v4.17.1

**EDIT**
Can ANYONE else reproduce this problem?

Comment: Is that your full code? Where is the part that listens to incoming connections on port 3000?

Comment: just updated with full code

Comment: In my opinion, the problem must be somewhere else. Your code is pretty much simple standard code and should definitely work

Comment: Please try `curl -X GET "http://localhost:3000/hello?id=123"` because maybe some characters have special meaning in your shell

Comment: In the end I had to downgrade to 3.* version