# How can I pass an argument in GET method?

Tags: node.js, redux, react-redux

I am currently using Redux and I want to send the state and request it in the backend. Code below.

```
const { email } = useSelector((state) => state.user);

  const getConcern = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/Student/", { email })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
    console.log(email);
    console.log(data);
  };
```

And I am trying to log it in the console in the backend but it results as undefined?

```
const getConcerns = async (req, res) => {
  const { email } = req.body;
  console.log(email);

  const concerns = await Concerns.find();

  res.status(200).json(concerns);
};
```

How can I send the email in the current state and pass it into the backend as a GET method? Please help, thanks.

Comment: Use `req.query` instead of `req.body` on the server, because you send data in the query string, not in the request body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get request doesn't have body you can use

```
await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/Student/", {
  params:{email}
})
```

and use req.query

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two issues here:

1. Axios expects a `data` property in the options object, so your `get` method call should look like:

```js
await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/Student/", { data: { email } })
```

2. While the [Http Spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#page-24) does not explicitly disallow sending a message body with a `GET` request, both the `XHR` and `fetch` APIs used by modern browsers ignore the message body when sending a `GET` request. Since Axios uses `XHR` in the browser, the data will be ignored. You can refactor your server route to a `POST` request if you need to receive data from the client in the request body. You could also use a [dynamic route parameter](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) or a [query parameter](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query).

Answer (score -1):

When you use GET, the request does not contain "body".

So, you have to use something like this:

```
req.query
```

Check [How to get GET (query string) variables in Express.js on Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-express-js-on-node-js?rq=1)