# ExpressJS - switching between multiple categories in API requests

Tags: node.js

I'm currently fetching below API from http://localhost:3009/api/get-products/ .
How do I switch between 10 categories and search using other keywords ?

```
    app.get("/api/get-products",async (req, res) => {
    client.execute('affiliate.product.query', {
    'app_signature':'mcc',
    'category_ids':'111,222,333',  <--- query different categories
    'keywords':'shirt',            <--- query different search keyword
    'target_currency':'USD',
    'target_language':'EN',
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use query parameters that allow you to specify what keywords or categories you want to receive:

Look at that example:
`https://example.com/over/there?name=ferret`.

While passing a query like that, you are able to get `name` from `req` object.

Here you can find more about the query parameters in Node.js: [How to get GET (query string) variables in Express.js on Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-express-js-on-node-js)