# How to access in Express.js information within?

Tags: node.js, express

Is there a way to use this url `http://localhost:3000/assets/img/1.jpg?50` instead of this `http://localhost:3000/assets/img/1.jpg/50`

```js
app.get('/assets/img/:file/:percentage', (req, res) =>{
        loadImagePercent(req, res, "private/img/"+req.params.file, req.params.percentage);
});
```

Comment: Express supports _query parameters_, yes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get GET (query string) variables in Express.js on Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-express-js-on-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

You can use query string:

```
app.get('/assets/img/:file', (req, res) => {
    loadImagePercent(req, res, "private/img/" + req.params.file, req.query.percentage);
});
```

And your url should be `http://localhost:3000/assets/img/1.jpg?percentage=50`