# Mongodb query returns null even the data is present in collection table using node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Here i'm checking with the collection `keys`, the `apikey` which im passing in postman it showing invalid credentials. the console value showing `null`. Dont know where im doing wrong thanks in advance

```
const fKey = await Key.findOne({
   password: req.params.apikey,
   active: true
});
console.log("fKey....",fKey)
```

postman :-[image]

Database:- [image]

Answer (score 0):

You Are Passing params instead of query in code

```
const fKey = await Key.findOne({
   password: req.query.apikey,
   active: true
});
console.log("fKey....",fKey)
```

please look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-express-js-on-node-js) for a better understanding.

Comment: i used `req.query.apikey` but still showing null

Comment: can you share the postman URL and the express route that you are calling ??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with MongoDB query. It is with request handling. You are using `req.params.apikey` instead of `req.query.apikey`.

```
const fKey = await Key.findOne({
   password: req.query.apikey,
   active: true
});
```

Comment: i used `req.query.apikey` but still showing null

Comment: @Mohan, here are the few things that you could do.

1. Log `req.params` & see if you are receiving the value from post man.
2. Log `req.query` & see if you are receiving `apikey` 
3. If the above 2 checks look normal, check to which database are connecting from the application. I mean, check the database host, port & especially database name.

Comment: @Mohan, what about `req.query` & `req.params` logs?

Comment: @Mohan are you connecting to `mongodb://localhost:27017/db` in the GUI that you show in the screenshot?

Comment: "Connection established with core database mongodb://localhost:27017/devotted_db"
this is the message i'm getting while connecting with server
and coming to logs for `req.query` -  { apikey: '0a51f05a-dd0d-41a1-b55b-8d125ea7c996' } and  - `req.params` - {}

Comment: So, using `req.query.apikey` is correct. Now ensure that you are connecting to correct database.

Comment: i'm connecting to same db which i have shown in screenshot and i checked in front-end that is working correctly. not an db  issue