# How do I consume the JSON POST data in an Express application

Tags: json, node.js, express

I'm sending the following JSON string to my server.

```
(
        {
        id = 1;
        name = foo;
    },
        {
        id = 2;
        name = bar;
    }
)
```

On the server I have this.

```
app.post('/', function(request, response) {

    console.log("Got response: " + response.statusCode);

    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
        queryResponse+=chunk;
        console.log('data');
    });

    response.on('end', function(){
        console.log('end');
    });
});
```

When I send the string, it shows that I got a 200 response, but those other two methods never run. Why is that?

Answer (score 734, accepted):

I think you're conflating the use of the `response` object with that of the `request`.

The `response` object is for sending the HTTP response back to the calling client, whereas you are wanting to access the body of the `request`. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4696338/112196) which provides some guidance.

If you are using valid JSON and are POSTing it with `Content-Type: application/json`, then you can use the [`bodyParser`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) middleware to parse the request body and place the result in `request.body` of your route.

**Update for Express 4.16+**

Starting with release 4.16.0, a new [`express.json()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.json) middleware is available.

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/', function(request, response){
  console.log(request.body);      // your JSON
   response.send(request.body);    // echo the result back
});

app.listen(3000);
```

**Updated for Express 4.0 - 4.15**

Body parser was split out into its own npm package after v4, requires a separate install `npm install body-parser`

```
var express = require('express')
  , bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/', function(request, response){
  console.log(request.body);      // your JSON
   response.send(request.body);    // echo the result back
});

app.listen(3000);
```

**For earlier versions of Express (< 4)**

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express.createServer();

app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/', function(request, response){
  console.log(request.body);      // your JSON
  response.send(request.body);    // echo the result back
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Test along the lines of:

```
$ curl -d '{"MyKey":"My Value"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://127.0.0.1:3000/
{"MyKey":"My Value"}
```

Comment: How would I access "MyKey" to get "My Value"?

Comment: How come it doesn't work for console.log("request = " + request.body)?

Comment: Because the concatenation invokes `toString()` on the object. Take a look at the node docs for `console.log`, as that inspects the object and returns a string representation.

Comment: I thought it was something like that. So how can I change it so it works?

Comment: `console.log('request =' + JSON.stringify(request.body))`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9706/discussion-between-neuromancer-and-pero-pejovic)

Comment: The current `console.log()` will automatically stringify an object (via `util.inspect()`), so this would work: `console.log("with request", request.body);`

Comment: Hi i have the following issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917401/node-js-express-request-entity-too-large/ and the following code: http://codepen.io/mike-jam-es/pen/hHbwJ Express: 3.4.4 If someone could provide some help on this it would be very much appreciated thanks!

Comment: This answer is outdated, but the one from @chrisarton is up to date.

Comment: @pero can you please help me with this: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/issues/213

Comment: I resolved PayloadTooLargeError by `app.use(express.json({ limit: "50mb" }));`

Comment: Outdated, pls look at the @chrisarton answer

Answer (score 226):

For Express v4+

install body-parser from the npm.

```
$ npm install body-parser
```

https://www.npmjs.org/package/body-parser#installation

```
var express    = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body) // populated!
  next()
})
```

Comment: why do they keep taking out stuff everyone uses?

Comment: @light24bulbs So it (Express) will be more lean and mean for those who don't use/need that.

Comment: @andyengle That does make sense.  But I think virtually everyone uses request parsing.  That seems like a core feature to me.

Comment: Since the middleware function interface is a standard used by many libraries, it also allows apps that don't use Express to use these middleware functions.

Comment: Taking it out of express doesn't allow it to be used by apps that do not use requests. They could have made it separate, and included it in express by default.

Comment: my body returns empty when data type is JSON

Comment: it works; is this line `app.use(bodyParser.json());` always needed to run before importing routes `app.use('/', require('./routes'));`?

Answer (score 65):

For those getting an empty object in `req.body`

I had forgotten to set 
`headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}`
in the request. Changing it solved the problem.

Comment: wow, thanks! life saver! easy to forget when invoking a lambda directly on the command line! `serverless invoke local -f app -l -d '{ "path": "/conferences", "httpMethod": "POST", "body": { "conference_name": "test" }, "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json"} }'`

Answer (score 28):

@Daniel Thompson mentions that he had forgotten to add {"Content-Type": "application/json"} in the **request**. He was able to change the request, however, changing requests is not always possible (we are working on the server here).

In my case I needed to force content-type: text/plain to be parsed as json.

If you cannot change the content-type of the request, try using the following code:

```
app.use(express.json({type: '*/*'}));
```

Instead of using express.json() globally, I prefer to apply it only where needed, for instance in a POST request:

```
app.post('/mypost', express.json({type: '*/*'}), (req, res) => {
  // echo json
  res.json(req.body);
});
```

Answer (score 22):

```js
const express = require('express');
let app = express();
app.use(express.json());
```

This app.use(express.json) will now let you read the incoming post JSON object

Answer (score 18):

Sometimes you don't need third party libraries to parse JSON from text.
Sometimes all you need it the following JS command, try it first:

```
        const res_data = JSON.parse(body);
```

Comment: The original question is about parsing JSON from a POST message in the Express framework. Without the BodyParser middleware, the JSON data will not exist in the body property of the request object.

Comment: Thank you Hasan, I appreciate your comment.
It did helped me when I was looking for solution and came across this post.
Not sure if it works in all cases but it definitely works in some and it is a better solution than using third party library.

Comment: Your answer and a comment provides the answer with more information (the more information being your answer here). You should update your answer to indicate that express needs the body-parser or give an alternative to indicate how body-parser got the data in the first place.

Comment: does not define `body`

Comment: But where do I get the string body?

Comment: This is enough to know when you write extensions that took care for parsing for you, for instance, building extension endpoints for directus.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this before your `app.post()`. I used `fetch()` instead of `axios()`, and I forgot to add the JSON parser.

```js
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(express.json());
```

Answer (score 0):

A beginner's mistake...i was using `app.use(express.json());` in a **local module** instead of the **main file** (entry point).

Comment: You can use it wherever you need it.