# Accessing JSON values in an express web server

Tags: json, web-services, parsing, node.js, express

I was able to use the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005939/how-to-consume-json-post-data-in-an-express-application) to access a value in a JSON string posted to the server.

If the server gets `{"MyKey":"My Value"}` then the value for `"MyKey"` can be accessed with `request.body.MyKey`.

But the JSON strings that get sent to my server look like this:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Aaa"},{"id":"2","name":"Bbb"}]
```

I could not find a way to access anything in that. How do you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.body` is a standard JavaScript object and in your case a vanilla JavaScript array. You would just handle `request.body` like you would any JavaScript [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) object. e.g.

```
app.post('/', function(request, response){
  var users = request.body;
  console.log(users.length);   // the length of the array

  var firstUser = users[0];    // access first element in array
  console.log(firstUser.name); // log the name

  users.forEach(function(item) { console.log(item) }); // iterate the array logging each item

  ...
```