# Using Nodemailer in an Ember.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, nodemailer

I am currently building a website with ember-cli. It’s fun and I make progress and learn this framework.

Now I want to use Nodemailer for sending an contact form. I figured it out how to send a mail with nodemailer from my terminal, but I don’t have a clue how it should work in combination with Ember. I simply don’t know how to connect the front-end to the back-end. And do I need to set up a server?

I haven’t build any Node.js apps yet, so please be so kind and give me a hint where I can find some advice without making an nodeschool.io course.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Asking for people to give you advice without pointing you to the standard places to learn tools is usually a bad way to get help! Try using the Node documentation, the Nodemailer documentation, and of course nodeschool, which is designed for this kind of learning!

Comment: Yes, you are right and you provided a reason for the down vote. Just hoped to find a faster way to get the result. But thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Express](http://expressjs.com/) to expose an API call that uses the json posted to the API to call Nodemailer. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10007542/77074) for how to consume data posted to the API. I assume since you've been playing with ember that you can work out how to post data captured in your form to the API.

Comment: I gonna chaco this out! Thank you!