# two different project request json parse error

Tags: node.js, express, request

I'm trying to do two different project request. I am request a using request module other project using express but json parse error in the express project

example object

```
var data= {
    User: {
        ID: 123
    },
    Text: 'hello world'
};

 request.post({
            headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
            url: "url/test",
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        }, function (error, response, body) {

            logger.debug("error : ", error);
            logger.debug("body : ", body);

        });
```

Listen a express project

```
app.post('/test', function(req, res) {

    try {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin || "*");
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

        console.log(req.body);
        var x = JSON.parse(req.body);

        res.send(200);

    } catch (error) {

        res.send(200);
    }
});
```

req.body is

{ '{"User":{"ID":123},"Text":"hello world"}'**: '' }**

erorr is

SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

beats extra single quote { '{"User":{"ID":123},"Text":"hello world"}'**: '' }**

Comment: I think its the same issue with this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005939/how-to-consume-json-post-data-in-an-express-application Basically, you need bodyParser to parse the json body

Comment: thanks punneng but bodyparse is on my code

Answer (score 0):

req.body is an object, not a simple string. The Javascript interpreter has already parsed it. This is why you see the mysterious `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1` message, despite there being no "o" in the JSON; JSON.parse is attempting a string operation on a non-string.

Answer (score 0):

you should add some options to your express app config and install body-parser package using `npm install body-parser` like this:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({
keepExtensions: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
```

Comment: i 've been trying like this 

// Body Parser
app.use(bodyParser.json());  // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    // to support URL-encoded bodies
    extended: true
}));
// Body Parser end

i will try your method. i write result

Comment: sorry no change :(

Comment: use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify((req.body))` to parsing json value