# Using AJAX Post and Node.js Express

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I am trying to send data from my html for node.js Express using a post method.

Using this code on my html file:

```
function readfile() {
var data = {};
data.path = '/home/test/pgadmin.txt';
data.ext = '.txt';
console.log(data);
  $.ajax({
    url: '/read_file',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
}
```

And this is the code that I'm using on server side.

```
var express = require('express')
var path = require('path')
var app = express()

app.post('/read_file', function(req, res) {
   console.log(req.data.path) //?
   console.log(req.data.ext) //?
   //I dont know how to get the values of my data: here

})
```

Is there some way to get those data values without using bodyparser?

Comment: the point of `bodyparser` is to be able to parse the request body - why don't you want to use bodyparser? look at the [source code to body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) and duplicate it ... or just use body-parser

Comment: Is it just parsing the body of request or of the entire html body?

Comment: `npm install body-parser` then `app.use(require("body-parser").json())` before your route

Comment: body-parser has nothing to do with the html `<body>` at all

Comment: How could I make it using body-parser?

Comment: It should be noted that body-parser is parsing the REQUEST body, not the HTML body.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you don't want to use `bodyParser`, but this could be done like:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/read_file', function(req, res) {
   console.log(req.body);
});
```

Of course you have to install `bodyParser` npm module as [Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43623243/using-ajax-post-and-node-js-express/43624290#comment74295504_43623243) pointed out.

See [How do I consume the JSON POST data in an Express application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005939/how-do-i-consume-the-json-post-data-in-an-express-application)