# $http in Angular how to post from form data in to nodejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have this form and the data is not appear they do not pass to my back end  :

```
<div ng-controller="searchController">
<form ng-submit="submit()">
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="namegirl" />
    <input type="text" name="namewod" ng-model="namewod" />
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Now in my controller in script.js is this:

```
myApp.controller('searchController', ['$scope', '$filter', '$http', function ($scope, $filter, $http) {

    let data = {
        namegirl  :$scope.namegirl,
        name      :$scope.namewod
    };

    console.log(data);

    $http.post('/wodsearch',data)
    .success(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
    })
    .error(function (response, status) {
        console.log(response);
    });

}]);
```

Now i wand to pass my data from my form to the nodejs in my server i have this code:

```
app.post('/wodsearch',function(req, res ,next){
    // how to get here the data from my angular  
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I consume the JSON POST data in an Express application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005939/how-do-i-consume-the-json-post-data-in-an-express-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `ng-submit="submit()"` when you post the form but there is no submit() method in the searchControllers scope. Add it like this

```
myApp.controller('searchController', ['$scope', '$filter', '$http'
, function ($scope, $filter, $http) {

    $scope.submit = function (){
        let data = {
            namegirl  :$scope.namegirl,
            name      :$scope.namewod
        };

        console.log(data);

        $http.post('/wodsearch',data)
        .success(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .error(function (response, status) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using [Express](http://expressjs.com/). 
Then the data should be in [req.body](http://expressjs.com/tr/api.html#req.body).