# JSON parse on a JSON string throws "Cannot convert object to primitive value"

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

**server.js**

uses the body parser middleware, handlebars and express

**route**

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.post('/questionnaire/submit', function (req, res) { // Ajax Call
        var data = JSON.parse(req.body);
        res.send({});
    });
};
```

**client**

```
function submitData() { // Send a data object to the server
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/questionnaire/submit',
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            satisfactory: "text 1",
            improvement: "text 2",
            rating: 0.7
        })
    }).done(function () {
        $(location).attr('href', '/sendOff');
    }).fail(function () {

    });
}
```

when logging `req.body` I get a JSON string

> { '{"satisfactory":"text 1","improvement":"text 2","rating":0.7}': '' }

and I try to parse this string to an object. When I do so, I get this error message

> ```
>      TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
>      at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
>      at C:\Users\mah\Desktop\FeedbackTool\Server\Routes\questionnaire.js:12:25
>      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\mah\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>      at next (C:\Users\mah\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>      at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\mah\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\mah\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>      at C:\Users\mah\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
>      at Function.process_params (C:\Users\mah\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>      at next (C:\Users\mah\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>      at C:\Users\mah\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:130:5
> ```

so how can I parse the string to an object?

Normally I would execute `JSON.parse(req.body)`.

Comment: *"when logging req.body I get a JSON string"* That doesn't look like a JSON string to me. It looks like something with JSON in it, but the `{ '` at the beginning isn't JSON (and the end looks odd).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It's a string in the form `{ '<json>': '' }`, ie an entire JSON document as the key of another JSON document, except you can't choose to use `'` in JSON, so the outer document isn't valid.

Comment: @meagar: Property names and other strings are always in double quotes in JSON. (Edit: Ah, you edited. :-) ) And since the OP is using `JSON.stringify`, we know it won't have single-quoted strings...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to setup correct contentType:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/questionnaire/submit',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ satisfactory: "text 1", rating: 0.7 })
});


app.post('/questionnaire/submit', function (req, res) { // Ajax Call
    var data = JSON.parse(req.body);
    console.log(data.rating); // 0.7
    res.send(data);
});
```

Also, with `body-parser` you may avoid `JSON.parse` calls on the server side, [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10007542/3211932).

Comment: But I didn't mention `body-parser` middleware... which is really important

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using `body-parser` middleware then you dont have to parse `req.body` again cause it already parsed by `body-parser`

Example

if you used 
`app.use(bodyParser.json())`

then you just have to do this

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.post('/questionnaire/submit', function (req, res) { // Ajax Call
        var data = req.body; // this is already parsed and is an object
        res.send({});
    });
};
```

as pointed out by @T.J. Crowder you should also send the correct `contentType` so `body-parser` knows its json

```
function submitData() { // Send a data object to the server
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/questionnaire/submit',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            satisfactory: "text 1",
            improvement: "text 2",
            rating: 0.7
        })
    }).done(function () {
        $(location).attr('href', '/sendOff');
    }).fail(function () {

    });
}
```

Comment: Good point. This is the other half of the problem (the first half is [sending the right `contentType`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47655729/157247)).

Answer (score 4):

`dataType` doesn't say what type of data you're **sending**, it says what type of response you expect. You need to say that you're sending JSON, via `contentType: "application/json"` in your `ajax` call. Details in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). (You're not the first or only person, by far, to be tripped up by the naming of `dataType`.)

That's half the problem. See [Stamos' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47655821/157247) for the other half.