# Using node.js how to send and store data from a simple HTML form

Tags: html, node.js, post

I am beginner to web development. I created a simple form using HTML and CSS, which contained three widgets i.e. name, email and phone. Now I want to send data to the server and store in it using NodeJS.
What should I do?

Here is my HTML file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <Meta charset = "uft-8">
        <title> Singing up for The Event </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    </head>
<body>
<form action = "/registration-form" method = "post">
    <div>
        <label for="name"> Name: </label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="mail"> E-mail: </label>
        <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_mail">
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="phone"> Phone:</label>
        <input type="number" id="phone" name="user_phone"></input>
    </div>

    <div class="button">
        <button type="submit">Register!</button>
    </div>

    <div class="button">
        <button type="Reset">Reset!</button>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my server.js file.

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
var port = process.env.PORT || 63342;

//POST
app.post('/api/users', function(req, res) {
    var user_name = req.body.user_name;
    var user_mail = req.body.user_mail;
    var user_phone = req.body.user_phone;

    res.send(user_name + ' ' + user_mail + ' ' + user_phone);
})

//starting the server
app.listen(port);
console.log("Running at port 63342...");
```

**I am not sure what to do next.** How to check if the request was successful and is there any way to make a request via opening and filling the HTML form directly.

[image]

Comment: _“Postman is not being successful, what address should write in URL box of the Postman?”_ - the one you want to send the request to would usually be a favorite …?

Comment: I mean when I run HTML file there also an address for that. Does that address have anything to do with it?

Comment: Well of course it would be … You specifically set up the route `/api/users` to handle these POST requests, so where else would you send them in the first place in this case? // This really rather sounds like you should go through some beginner’s tutorials on the matter, rather than asking about such specifics here.

Comment: Yes, I guess it's better to follow a simple NodeJS/Express tutorial, because when you get your post successful, how do you want to store your data?, database?, files?, you don't have anything in your code about that.

Comment: I already gave that address too, it gives undefined for all three variables.

Comment: The URL you need to POST to is "localhost:63342/api/users". Which URL are you trying ?

Comment: @Vishal-Lia yes, i am using this URL

Comment: Can you share your HTML part also?

Comment: @Vishal-Lia I just did, check it out.

Comment: I guess form action should be "localhost:63342/api/users", so once u submit the form u will have a POST request.   <form action = "localhost:63342/api/users" method = "post">

Comment: @Vishal-Lia I changed that, but the problem remains. When I open the HTML file, it has URL localhost/63342 (I was confused about the URL because of the port number)  but when I try to run server.js on the same port it gives me error.Now I changed the port of server.js to 3000. Now it is running just fine. Postman is giving status 200(ok) but in the preview window it gives undefined for all three parameters.

Comment: Please, check the image.

Comment: @Goodfellow I think (not sure) that your JSON in `req.body` is not parsed and is still raw text. Use `const data = JSON.parse(req.body);`. Also might be a duplicate of this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005939/how-do-i-consume-the-json-post-data-in-an-express-application

Answer (score 0):

How did you define your model schema(database) or collections : you can check value of the response(res).

```
  if(err) {
        res.json({success: false, message: `Failed to create a new list. Error: ${err}`});
    }
    else
        res.json({success:true, message: "Added User successfully."});
```