# Can't get JSON data from client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

I want to send JSON data from client side to server side.

Client side:

```
function send() {
    var formData = {
        firstname: $("#name").val(),
        lastname: $("#lastname").val()
    }

    console.log("sending: " + JSON.stringify(formData));

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "/dat",
        data: JSON.stringify(formData),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(customer) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(customer));
        },
        error: function(e) {
            alert("Error!")
            console.log("ERROR: ", e);
        }
    });
}
```

Server side:

```
app.post("/dat", function (req, res) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body)); // return undefined
    res.end(JSON.stringify({ "nine": 9, "ten": 10, "eleven": 11 }));
});
```

I tried everything, but `JSON.stringify(req.body)` return only `undefined`. Sending data from server to client side working just fine...
Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm going to assume you're using Express. Have you installed [`body-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#installation)? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24635296/965834 for usage example.

Comment: @Jeto yes, I got that.
I have this: `const bodyParser = require("body-parser");` and `app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Comment: Are you sure you're doing that before defining routes?

Comment: @Jeto yes, I am sure... I uploaded my code to gitlab: https://gitlab.com/JaroslavVond/nodejs/tree/master/NodeServer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're resetting `app` [here](https://gitlab.com/JaroslavVond/nodejs/blob/master/NodeServer/Server.js#L37) with:

```
var app = express();
```

Remove that line.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, Thank you so much!!

Comment: If I get it right... every time when I did POST, the server restarted or set some default settings?

Comment: @KoRaPCZ More like, everything that happened before that line got cancelled because you replaced the existing `app` variable with a brand new one. The session thing, the body-parser setup, etc.

Comment: I see. Thank you for help