# ReferenceError: email is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs, express

Hi Please help a struggling dev.

I have been trying all day to get this fixed to no avail. Essentially all I want to to do is post from my AddUsers class and for this to be stored through to my sql database. It is a very simple query but has gotten the better off me!The state is updated on change but seems to be an issue with the server.js (error included at bottom of post)

Server.js

```
app.post("/admin-Add-Users", function(req, res) {
  var request = new sql.Request();

  // query to the database and get the records
  request.query(
    "insert into Login (email, password) values ('" +
      req.body.email +
      "','" +
      req.body.password +
      "')",
    function(err, recordset) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
    }
  );
  res.send({ message: "Success" });
});
```

AddUsers class

```
class AddUsers extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = { users: [], email: "", password: "" };
    this.onSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = { email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password };

    fetch("/admin-Add-Users", {
      method: "POST", // or 'PUT'
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log("Success:", data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.users);
    return (
      <div>
        <LoginForm></LoginForm>

        <form>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="email"
            value={this.state.email}
            onChange={e => this.setState({ email: e.target.value })}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="password"
            value={this.state.password}
            onChange={e => this.setState({ password: e.target.value })}
          />
          <input type="submit" onClick={this.onSubmit} />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```
ReferenceError: email is not defined
```

UPDATE: After trying recommendations I have been given I now revive a new error.

```
Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Comment: Please, do not change your question in a way that it invalidates existing answers.

Comment: Note that your `res.send({ message: "Success" });` will always be sent, regardless of the result of the sql request since you've put it outside the callback.

Comment: I have reedited title

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I consume the JSON POST data in an Express application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005939/how-do-i-consume-the-json-post-data-in-an-express-application)

Comment: Did you add `app.use(express.urlencoded());` to server ?

Comment: Have fixed the issue in the code I have submitted as a answer. If you were interested check it out should be a bit down this page :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like there is nothing wrong in your React app.

> The problem is at your API end where you're formulating an `insert` query without actually reading the request json content (email & password) fields.

You could add following lines before the query is being generated.

```js
// create sql obj
...
var email = req.body.email;
var password = req.body.password;

...
// your query
```

Comment: Thanks! I have added that into my server.js file. I am now receiving this error.

Comment: Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: You might wanna go over this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10007542/1263904

Comment: No luck unfortunately :(

Comment: Are you using any json middleware for express? With express 4.16+, you could use `app.use(express.json());` during the app initialization.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add middleware to your express app to be able to parse request body's.

Try adding this to the file where you configure express:

```
    app.use(express.json());
```

Answer (score 0):

email and password fields must be retrieved from req

Comment: Thanks for the advice. How would I implement this ?

Comment: ``` 
app.post("/admin-Add-Users", function(req, res) {
  var request = new sql.Request();

  // query to the database and get the records
  request.query(
    "insert into Login (email, password) values ('" +
      req.body.email +
      "','" +
      req.body.password +
      "')",
    function(err, recordset) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
    }
  );
  res.send({ message: "Success" });
});```

Comment: solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59615541/12661052)

Comment: Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your answer. What do you mean by "retrieved from req"?

Comment: req.body is a json build. it must be transformed into an object. Use app.use (express.json ());

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer but it turns out the issue is related to CORS. I am not sure of the solution at this point ,but I am fairly sure this is the cause.

Thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Everyone thanks for all your help. I fixed this issue by using the following code within my server.js

```
app.post("/admin-Add-Users", async (req, response) => {
  sql.connect(config, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      response.status(400);
      response.send(err);
    } else {
      try {
        // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request();

        var body = req.body;

        console.log(body);

        if (body) {
          var email = body.email;
          var password = body.password;

          var queryString = `insert into Login (email,password) values ('${email}', '${password}')`;

          console.log(queryString);

          request.query(queryString, function(err, recordset) {
            console.log(err);
            response.status(400);
            // response.send(err);
          });

          response.status(201);
          response.send("User added ");
        } else {
          response.status(400);
          response.send("no content was provided");
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        response.status(400);
        response.send(e);
      }
    }
  });
});
```