# NodeJS / Express: Get Username and Password from Request

Tags: node.js, express

I am using NodeJS and Express, and I want to get the Username and Password parameters from a request. I've searched for a while now, and I can't find my answer.

I want to accept a `user` parameter from a cURL command:

```
curl --request --POST -u USERNAME:PASSWORD -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{\"key":\"value\"}" --url https://api.example.com/my_endpoint
```

In my application:

```
app.post('/my_endpoint', async (req, res, next) => {
    const kwargs =. req.body;
    const userName = req['?'];
    const password = req['?'];
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are sending the credentials as a basic-auth header (since you're using curl's `-u` option). So in order to get the credentials from your request, you need to access this header and decode it. Here's one way to do this:

```
app.post('/my_endpoint', async (req, res, next) => {
   if(req.headers.authorization) {
     const base64Credentials = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
     const credentials = Buffer.from(base64Credentials, 'base64').toString('utf8');
     const [username, password] = credentials.split(':');
     console.log(username, password);
   }
});
```

Comment: I have been looking for a simple answer for so long, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[How do I consume the JSON POST data in an Express application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005939/how-do-i-consume-the-json-post-data-in-an-express-application)

**I would do it this way**

Assuming your call includes json content like this :

Remove **-u USERNAME:PASSWORD**

Edit **-d "{ "username": "user", "password": "test" }"**

```
curl --request --POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{ "username": "user", "password": "test" }" --url https://api.example.com/my_endpoint
```

Then you can access those variables with :

```
const userName = req.body.username;
const password = req.body.password;
```

Be careful, you need to use [bodyParser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) middleware in express in order to be able to access the body variables.

Comment: I am definitely not passing the username and password in the body of the request. That is not safe.

Comment: Depends on the encryption but yes, this is not the best way ! Sorry