# Can't send data through axios and node back-end

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I am trying to access the expression passed from the backend to the frontend through axios.

Producer side:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const URL = "http://localhost:5000/"
let n1 = 3
let n2 = 5
let sum = n1+n2;



axios.post(URL, JSON.stringify({
    expression: sum,
  }))
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

and on the consumer side:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
})

app.listen(5000, () => console.log())
```

Ultimately, I would like to have the consumer side log "8"

Comment: And what are you actually seeing?

Comment: At the moment, I have console.log(req) which gives me a large object. I would like to console.log(req.body) to return the value of the defined variable 'sum'

Comment: Maybe this is the answer you need
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005939/how-do-i-consume-the-json-post-data-in-an-express-application

Comment: On the client-side, I don't think the `JSON.stringify` method is necessary. Try to remove it. Document here: https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert to JSON, axios serves JSON natively.

Add to the server:

```js
app.use(express.json())
```

Just send you data:

```js
axios.post(URL, { expression: sum, })
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.err)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the ["express" documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html):

> **req.body**
>
> Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. By default, it is ***undefined***, and is populated when you use body-parsing middleware such as body-parser and multer.

Try including this before you try to register the endpoint:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

You can also use `express.json()` and drop the 'body-parser' dependency:

```
// const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(express.json())
```

Comment: Hey, I have tried this method, and I am getting ```{}```
this is a good start. I would like to return ```13```

Answer (score 0):

Axios have some security measures as well, you should put your IP address in
const `URL = "http://localhost:5000/"`