# What is req.body in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am learning nodejs and express, during my studies I don't understand various uses of `req` such as:

```
var id = req.params.id;
var wine = req.body;
```

With my `req` object I think am acessing `body, params.id`, but I do not understand how this works and what result I should expect. Can anyone explain this code in a simpler step by step manner so i can make sense of it ?

Below is some example code where the above is used :

```
 exports.addDoctor = function(req,res){
        var doctor = req.body;
        console.log(doctor);
            db.collection('doctors',function(err,collection){
            collection.insert(doctor,{safe:true},function(err,result){
                if (err) {
                    res.send({'error':'An error is occured'});
                } else {
                    console.log('Success: ' + JSON.stringify(result[0]));
                    res.send(result[0]);
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

In the above example `console.log(doctor)` only returns `{}`. Why is this and is it because I have missed something else within the code specifically involving 'req'?

Comment: `{}` is a JavaScript [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

Comment: It's all in the documentation -- [req.body](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.body) is here, [req.params](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.params) here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`req` is the request object. It's documented here: http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.params

Answer (score 1):

req is an object containing information about the HTTP request that raised the event. There is a simular Question ([node.js what is res and req in expressjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696283/node-js-what-is-res-and-req-in-expressjs)), have a look at the answers there.