# FIXED: SailsJs + Google Blogger is timing out

Tags: google-api, blogger, sails.js

So I've been tinkering with SailsJs and really like it so far, but I am trying to pull from posts from a blog I own into a view.  This is a bit of a problem because the connection times out when trying to get the index view, and there is no feedback from the console via the console.log entries.

#### Blogger Service

```js
// BloggerService.js - in api/services
var g = require('googleapis');
var apiKey = 'OUche33eekym0nKEY-uME';

exports.getBlogPosts = function(options, cb) {
    g.discover('blogger', 'v3').execute(function(err, client) {
            if(err) {
                    cb = null;
                    return console.log(err);
            } else {
                    var opts = { 'blogId': options.id, 'maxResults': options.limit, 'fields': 'items(title,content,url)' };
                    cb = client.blogger.posts.list(opts);
            };
    });
};

exports.getBlogPost = function(options, cb) {
    g.discover('blogger', 'v3').execute(function(err, client) {
            if(err) {
                    cb = null;
                    return console.log(err);
            } else {
                    var opts = { 'blogId': options.id, 'postId': options.postId };
                    cb = client.blogger.posts.get(opts);
            };
    });
};
```

Calling the service in the controller.  [Frustrating because the bottom of the documentation has a very cavalier way of saying where/how the service is called.](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/0.9/services.md)

#### BlogController.js

```js
/**
 * BlogController.js
 *
 * @description ::
 * @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/controllers
 */

module.exports = {
    index: function(req, res){
            BloggerService.getBlogPosts({'id':'86753098675309','limit':6},function(err, blogPosts){
                    if(err){
                            return console.log(err);
                    } else {
                            console.log(blogPosts.items[0].url);
                            res = blogPosts;
                    };
            });
    }
}
```

#### Index view

```xml
<div>
            <% _.each(Model.items, function (blogPost) { %>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading"><%= blogPost.title %></div>
                            <div class="panel-body"><%= blogPost.content %><input type="hidden" value="<%= blogPost.id %>"></div>
                    </div>
            <% }) %>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you for the time you spent looking at this.

#### UPDATE

Many thanks to Scott, who got me closer to the end results.  This is what I have thus far, but just need to clear up an authentication issue with discover/apiKeys.

```js
exports.getBlogPosts = function(options, cb) {
    g.discover('blogger', 'v3').execute(function(err, client) {
            if(err) {
                    cb(err);
            } else {
                    var opts = { 'blogId': options.id, 'maxResults': options.limit, 'fetchBodies': false, 'fields': 'items(title,url)' }
                    client.blogger.posts.list(opts).withApiKey(apiKey).execute(cb);
            };
    });
 };

exports.getBlogPost = function(options, cb) {
    g.discover('blogger', 'v3').execute(function(err, client) {
            if(err) {
                    cb(err);
            } else {
                    var opts = { 'blogId': options.id, 'postId': options.postId };
                    client.blogger.posts.get(opts).withApiKey(apiKey).execute(cb);
            };
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might be new to Node.js, so you might want to read up on [asynchronous programming with Node](http://book.mixu.net/node/ch7.html) and the [req and res objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696283/node-js-what-is-res-and-req-in-expressjs) used by Express.  The two problems I see with your code right off the bat are:

1. That you're assigning a value to your callback in `BloggerService.js`, rather than actually *calling* the callback: `cb = client.blogger.posts.list(opts)` should be (based on a quick scan of the Google API docs) `client.blogger.posts.list(opts).execute(cb)`, and in case of an error `cb = null` should be `cb(err)`.
2. You're assigning a value to the response object, instead of sending a response: `res = blogPosts` should be `res.json(blogPosts)`.

As far as where / when you call your service, the docs aren't intending to be cavalier.  The services are globalized so that they can be called from anywhere within any controller; it's up to you as the developer to decide where you need your service calls to be!

Comment: This answered _precisely_ what I needed to know.  Even with a cursory check, you nailed it.  Thank you very much.  I'm just having an issue with setting the ApiKey, but that is beyond the scope of my question.