# ExpressJS Error: Body-Parser Deprecated

Tags: node.js, express, deprecated, body-parser

**Question**
I'm trying build a Node.js API, when write my server.js file, my code looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var express = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/api/posts', function(req,res) {
res.json([
    {
        username: 'oscar',
        body: 'hello'
    }

])
})

app.listen(3000, function() {
console.log('Server Listening on', 3000)
})
```

However, in the command prompt I am getting this error:

```
body-parser deprecated bodyParser: use individual json.urlencoded
middlewares server.js:4:11
body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option
node_modules\body-parser\index.js:85:29
```

I tried changing this to :

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

and

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```

like other posts suggest, but it still gives the same error. Not sure what to do now! Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

```
var app = express();

// configure body-parser

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Answer (score 5):

I had similar deprecated warning. Here's my original code:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
```

Adding `{extended: true}` fixed the warning for me. Here's changed code:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a typo, change:

```
var express = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

to:

```
var bodyParser   = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser());
```

Do have a look at what the request and response objects do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696283/node-js-what-is-res-and-req-in-expressjs)

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need the line `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));`

I've got it to work with the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

As log as you have `app.user(bodyParser.json());` you shouldn't get the error.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `body-parser` module any more with current express.js versions (≥ 4.16).

Instead, use the json parser already included in express:

```
app.use(express.json())
```

Source: https://expressjs.com/en/changelog/4x.html#4.16.0

Answer (score 2):

## Don't use body-parser

In new versions of express, body parsing is now builtin. So, you can simply use

```
app.use(express.json()) //For JSON requests
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

from directly express

You can uninstall body-parser using `npm uninstall body-parser`

**Then you can simply get the POST content from `req.body`**

```
app.post("/yourpath", (req, res)=>{

    var postData = req.body;

    //Or for string JSON body, you can use this

    var postData = JSON.parse(req.body);
});
```