# How to get Request in a Controller

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I use Express with Typescript and Controllers. I try to make a BaseController who contains Request and Response of each request. I tried something like this but it doesn't work.

```
export * as express from 'express';

const req = express.Request;
```

Comment: The request and response are passed in the controller methods that handle them. They are not global objects https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696283/what-are-res-and-req-parameters-in-express-functions

Answer (score 0):

You can create "`Controller`" classes to group your *[route handlers](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)*, but Express always pass `req` and `res` (Request and Response objects) to the route handlers.

Exemple using TypeScript:

```
// very simplistic example

// "Controller" class
export class UsersController {
  // route handler
  async getUsers(req: Request, res: Response) {
    try {
      const users = await this.usersRepository.fetchUsers();
      return res.json(users);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      return res.status(500).end();
    }
  }
}
```

And somewhere with your Express router:

```
const usersController = new UsersController();
app.get('/users', usersController.getUsers);
```

As a bonus suggestion, I'd recommend having a look at the [Nest](https://nestjs.com/) project, which offers a great developer experience to anyone eager to use both TypeScript and Express together.