# localhost doesn't output the JSON for Router and controller i used

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, model-view-controller, middleware

I have just started to learn `NodeJS` and I am stuck with this. I am trying to handle the request. The `localhost` keeps loading or throws an error

> cannot GET/

The `JSON` code needs to be displayed on my `localhost` site. What changes to `routes` or `controllers` should I make?

Here is the `app.js` file that calls the router to handle the request.

**app.js**

```
const express=require("express");
const app=express();

const Postroutes=require('./routes/post');

app.use("/" , Postroutes);

const port=8000;
app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`a node js api is listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

the routes will forward the request to the controller.

**routes/post.js**

```
const express= require("express")
const PostController=require('../controllers/post')

const router=express.Router()

router.get("/",PostController.getPosts);

module.exports= router;
```

The controller will respond with the JSON.

**controllers/post.js**

```
exports.getPosts= (req,res)=>{
    res.json=({
        posts:
            [
                {title:"First Post"},
                {title:"Second Post"}

            ]
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In `controllers/post.js`

Try `res.json({...});` instead `res.json=({...});`

Answer (score 1):

This can be use inside your `controllers/post.js`

```js
exports.getPosts= (req,res)=>{
    const json = {
        posts:
            [
                {title:"First Post"},
                {title:"Second Post"}

            ]
    };
    res.send(json);
};
```

Or use `res.json({ ... })` as per @lolmc answer.

More about response for different format -> [Express API Ref](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res)

Comment: I get this error: =       throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))   What does this mean?  @Sandeep Kumar

Answer (score 0):

As both Abhishek and lolmc mentioned `res.json({...})` should do the trick. `res` is an object with methods. These methods responds to the HTTP request.

`res` is short for response.
e.g. `res.json({ message: 'This is a test message.' })` to reply to a HTTP request with json.

See [this post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4696338/5372353) where Dave Ward explains `req` and `res` and read [the docs for res](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res) and [the docs for req](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req) to learn more.